# Closure of central subgroup is a central subgroup of closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, topological-groups, algebraic-groups

Consider $G$ a linear algebraic group and $A\leq B\leq G$ two subgroups with no topological structure. Suppose $A$ is central in $B$, that is $A\leq Z(B)$, we want to show that $\overline{A}\leq Z(\overline{B})$.
I was thinking about using some map $\phi_b:G\to G$ defined by $\phi_b(g)=gb-bg$ and use some kind of properties closure under continuous maps but I can't quite get it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What is an algebraic group for you? When you say $A\leq G$, do you mean that $A$ is a subgroup of the group of $K$-points $G(K)$ where $K$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: I'm using 'Algebraic Transformation Groups - an Introduction' by Hanspeter Kraft if that helps. A linear algebraic group is a closed subgroup of $GL_n=GL_n(\mathbb C)$, where it has the Zariski topology. So here I really mean standard group theory, but we add some topology structure on it. For $A\leq G$ I just mean that it's a subgroup, as I said $A,B$ are just considered as classical subgroups, no Zariski here. I doubt that it has something special to do with this topology, maybe it's true for topological groups in general.

Comment: Notably, $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is not a topological group under the Zariski topology. $T_0$ topological groups are always Hausdorff, but the Zariski topology on $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ never is (for $n > 0$). However, $A \leq Z(B) \implies \overline{A} \leq Z(\overline{B})$ does hold in all $T_0$ topological groups!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All $T_0$ topological groups are Hausdorff. And, in all Hausdorff topological groups, it is true that $A \leq Z(B)$ implies $\overline{A} \leq Z(\overline{B})$.

By your definition, all algebraic groups are $T_0$ (the Zariski topology on a quasi-affine variety always is), but only finite algebraic groups will be Hausdorff. So, most of the algebraic groups you want to consider will not be topological groups.

However, your algebraic groups *are* group objects in the category of quasi-affine varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. So, we can try to translate the argument for topological groups to the category of quasi-affine varieties, and this works!

---

Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. The map $c = (x,y) \mapsto xyx^{-1}y^{-1} : \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \to \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is continuous, where $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the product variety.

$A \leq Z(B)$ is equivalent to the following two conditions:

1. $A \leq B$
2. $A \times B \leq c^{-1}(I)$.

The first condition implies that $\overline{A} \leq \overline{B}$. Since $\{I\}$ is closed in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, the second condition implies that $\overline{A \times B} \leq c^{-1}(I)$. So, it suffices to show that $\overline{A} \times \overline{B} \leq \overline{A \times B}$.

Let $(x,y) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ be arbitrary. Let $f$ be a regular function on $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and suppose $f$ vanishes on $A \times B$. Then for all $a \in A$, the function $y \mapsto f(a,y) : \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \to \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ vanishes on $B$, so it vanishes on $\overline{B}$. Now for all $b \in \overline{B}$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,b)$ vanishes on $A$, so it vanishes on $\overline{A}$. We conclude that $f$ vanishes on $\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$. Since $f$ was arbitrary, this shows that $\overline{A} \times \overline{B} \leq \overline{A \times B}$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: Thank you. First I'm not sure to understand the argument, why exactly are we considering regular functions, why does it imply what we wanted ? And second, you're saying that algebraic groups are not topological groups ? We have that algebraic groups have a structure of (affine) varieties, and that group multiplication and inverse are morphisms of (affine) varieties are continuous so it "should" be a topological group no ?

Comment: @rainsec The problem is that the Zariski topology on $X \times X$ is *not* the product topology coming from the Zariski topology on $X$. When we say that the group multiplication $X \times X \to X$ is continuous, it is with respect to the Zariski topology, not the product topology! And so, in general, algebraic groups (by your definition) are not topological groups.

Comment: The basic closed sets in the Zariski topology are precisely the zero loci of regular functions. So, if we show that every regular function that vanishes on $A \times B$ also vanishes on $\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, we conclude that $\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ is contained in all closed supersets of $A \times B$. This means that $\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ is contained in the closure of $A \times B$.